# How do I get my code to accept more than one username and password?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, passwords

I have a website that I "programmed" with HTML, and I found a script (JavaScript) to get a password for when the site is under maintenance. It currently only accepts a single username and password, is it possible to make it accept more than one? **This is not my code, I found it online and want to add to it. This project is purely for educational purposes.**

**Side note, I don't have a ton of experience, and people just down voting the question is not going to help me learn how to do this. I am a student in high school still learning these languages and the only way to learn is to get help when I need it.

```
<form name="login">
    Username  <input type="text" name="userid" />
    Password  <input type="password" name="pswrd" />
    <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login" />
    <button formaction="/index.html">Cancel</button>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
    function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
    {
         /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
         if(form.userid.value == "example-username" && form.pswrd.value == "example-password")
         {
             window.open("/mainpage.html")/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
         }
         else
         {
             alert("Error Password or Username")/*displays error message*/
         }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you aware that this script provides exactly no security? Literally anybody can access `/mainpage.html`. Simply looking at the page source reveals your username and password, and also shows the name of the file you're trying to protect so it can be loaded directly.

Comment: Yes, it is just to keep the idiots in my school out, and I mostly programmed this in because I wanted to learn how.

Comment: Learning how to do things the wrong way now will cost you in the long run. You'll have to break bad habits later when you start learning the right way to do things. You've tagged this question with PHP. Are you using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link: [If Statements][1]

[1]: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp under the logical operators section. You will need to apply that logic to the following line

```
if(form.userid.value == "example-username" && form.pswrd.value == "example-password")
```

basically, duplicate the condition after the logic operator for a second person

```
if(form.userid.value == "example-username" && form.pswrd.value == "example-password" || form.userid.value == "example-username2" && form.pswrd.value == "example-password2")
```

as Chris Stated, this is by no means secure and would require a backend system and database to handle login checks. In this format anyone could simply view the JS code and obtain the password or, in the url, type the www.example.com/mainpage.html to completely bypass your login.